# Get Azure devops team members in powerbi

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi

I need to link teams to team members in a Power BI report.

It seems trivial but I can't find the data in the ODATA API.

Comment: By Link you mean integrate ?  if this so have to check A Power BI Pro license,
The Power BI tab for Microsoft Teams,The user must have permissions and access to view the report.

Comment: By link I mean I need to have in the report, what are the members of each team

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that the ODATA API couldn't get the team members in Azure Devops.

According to this [ODATA API Data relationships chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-dataset?view=azure-devops#data-relationships), the Team Object only supports the `Team SK` , `Team Id` and `Team name` properties. So the API result will not contains the team members.

Test it with the URL:

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/organizaiton name /Project name/_odata/v2.0/teams
```

Result:

[image]

The result contains its own attributes and associated attributes. But there is no field could show the team members.

**Workaround:**

Now, the [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/teams/get%20team%20members%20with%20extended%20properties?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) supports to output the team members.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects/{projectId}/teams/{teamId}/members?api-version=5.1
```

You could save the response as `.Json file` and input the file to PowerBi.

Hope this could give you some help.